# Can my unwieldy SUMIFS VBA code be streamlined?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I would like to start this by saying I know enough VBA coding "to be dangerous" as the old saying goes.

I work at a library and was given a report from the system to make into a table with sums. I had done this before for another report with Countifs (that obviously needed counts instead of sums) and it was fairly streamlined. When I got into this report though that needed the Sumifs formula, I encountered an error about the procedure being too large. After searching the web, I figured out I needed to break up my sub into smaller procedures. That's fine and dandy, but I feel like my code might be terribly inefficient for what I am doing. Can someone look it over and tell me if there is a better way to do this?

This is the report:

[image: Report from system]

This is how it should look when done:

[image: Table of sum of report lines]

This report is looking at "owning libraries" (the libraries that actually own the book/material) and the "circing library" (the library that actually circulated the book/material) and the resulting table sums the report lines of each.

I had to break up my procedures as so:

[image: One overall sub with calls for seven procedures]

And this is what my sumifs coding looks like:

[image: SOOO many lines of sumifs formulas]

All this works but I feel like it is terribly unwieldy and there is probably a more streamlined way to code this. Please let me know if you need more info and I will update the post.

[Edit] - I will add that there are 40 locations (rows) by 24 locations (columns), so 960 cells in this table/grid of sums (not just what is in the screenshot), plus three columns & rows for different totals.

Comment: I am not a VBA programmer. Are you asking if you can create an array with these values (shortened name, long name, and column) and loop through them (with a For Each Loop) to assign the ranges? If so, probably. That would make the code a lot more readable.

Comment: Are you able to share the code?

Comment: Wouldn't a PivotTable be a simpler, more efficient and less 'fragile' (potentially buggy) method of doing this?

Comment: @AdamV Unfortunately, there are fields that need to be combined & some that take a % of the total & I find Pivot Tables don't always allow a great deal of customization of just one field or another (more of an all or nothing approach). I also need to add a lot of calculation columns & rows that are also highly customized (these branches, but not these others ones in this line; this other line is always 0 even if there are numbers) It's kind of crazy how they want some of these, but it's what they want and they want it to apply to every report of that type they run, not just a one time thing.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are doing is a primary loop on branch name (I'd probably use branchnumber); then looping on a town code (Irondeqouit; Henrietta etc.). The destination column is tied in some way to the branchnumber; the destination row is tied to the town code.

Need to store:
the branch name along with: row;
the towncodes along with: column;

There are a number of choices but an array of a user-defined type or a dictionary might make the most sense.

Below is a totally untested (and un-spellchecked) way of generalizing. It is not the only way. If I were doing something like this I would probably declare the user-type arrays outside the sub and pass them etc.

```
option explicit  

Type towncodeType
 code as string
 displaycol as string 
end Type

Type branchType 
 branchname as string
 displayrow as string
End Type

sub onePossibleWay()


dim branchCount as long
dim townCount as long
dim destRange as string    
dim alltowns(10) as towncodeType  ' change 10 to total number of towns
dim allBranches(20) as branchType   ' change 20 to total number of branches

alltowns(0).code = "BROCK"
alltowns(0).displaycol = "C"

[...] one entry per town, remember to increment the index

allBranches(0).branchname = "Arnett Branch Library"
allBranches(0).diisplayrow = "4"

[...] one entry per branch

for branchcount = 0 to ubound(allbranches)-1
    for towncount = 0 to ubound(alltowns)-1
        destRange = alltowns(towncount).displaycol & allbranches(branchcount).displayrow
        wst.Range(destRange) = application.worksheetfunction.sumifs(wsr.range(H:H"), wsr.range("G:G"), alltowns(towncount).code, wsr.range("E:E"),  allbranches(branchcount).branchname
    next towncount
next branchcount

end sub
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need, but unfortunately, when I plugged it in, I was getting an error. I need to work with it and figure out the problem, but this is definitely the right track. I need to brush up on arrays and get over my fear of them (they remind me too much of complex math problems, haha!). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do away with the VBA entirely and use PowerQuery instead.

Select your table, then use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range. The Power Query editor will open:

[image]

Select the 'TRACT' column and use Transform>Pivot Column. Configure it like this:

[image]

When you click OK, you will see the TRACT values as column headers and the branch names and branch numbers as row headers, like this:

[image]

If you want to re-order the TRACT columns, you can do that by dragging them to the place you'd like them to appear. You can also rename them, or change the format.

There are many other transformations you can apply to the data to clean it up to be how you'd like.

You can now use Home>Close & Load to put the results of the query back into the spreadsheet.

When new data are added to the source table, you can re-run the query by right-clicking it and choosing 'Refresh':

[image]